# Is there a way to convert (unflatten) ModelState Keys and values from Mvc to objects?

Tags: asp.net-mvc

I would like to take a `System.Web.Mvc.ModelStateDictionary` and convert it (unflatten) to a readable object that can be serialized safely in Json for logging.

The Model State Input looks something like this:

```
{
    "FirstName": "Somebody",
    "LastName": "Awesome",
    "Emails[0].EmailType": "Primary",
    "Emails[0].EmailAddress": "asdf@tempuri.com",
    "Emails[0].UpdatedBy": "tester",
    "UpdatedBy": null
}
```

What I want for output would be something like this:

```
{
    "Emails": {
        "0": {
            "EmailAddress": "asdf@tempuri.com",
            "EmailType": "Primary",
            "UpdatedBy": "tester"
        }
    },
    "FirstName": "Somebody",
    "LastName": "Awesome",
    "UpdatedBy": null
}
```

Is there a built in way to accomplish this with Mvc or even an external library?

Answer (score 0):

The home-grown function to do this is:

```
        public Dictionary<string, object> Convert(ModelStateDictionary modelState)
        {
            var o = new Dictionary<string, object>();

            var sorted = modelState.OrderBy(_ => _.Key).ToList();

            foreach (var ms in sorted)
            {
                string key = ms.Key;
                // each key starts at the root node
                var node = o;
                int i = 0;
                int ic = 0;
                string token;

                // extract each token and build dictionaries
                for (; i < key.Length - 1; i++)
                {
                    var c = key[i];
                    switch (c)
                    {
                        case '.':
                        // don't bother with lists just use a dictionary, just easier!
                        case '[':
                        case ']':
                            if (i - ic > 0)
                            {
                                token = key.Substring(ic, i - ic);
                                if (!node.TryGetValue(token, out var cn) || !(cn is Dictionary<string, object> v))
                                {
                                    node[token] = v = new Dictionary<string, object>();
                                }
                                node = v;
                            }
                            ic = i + 1;
                            break;
                        default:
                            break;
                    }
                }
                i++;

                token = key.Substring(ic, i - ic);
                node[token] = ms.Value.Value?.AttemptedValue;
            }

            return o;
        }
```